# How can I download GISGraphy CSV Files for a particular country?

Tags: csv, download, gisgraphy

So, the files have been removed from the server due to some hacking issues and I need the CSV files urgently.

How and from where can I download these CSVs? 
 GISGraphy is setup on my system, only the CSV are missing.

Comment: you have to contact them http://download.gisgraphy.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it dependent on access to data on a server with some issues currently

Answer (score 3):

I would e-mail them, they have the contact and mention if you need it urgently to do so, [here](http://download.gisgraphy.com/)

> Due to people that have abused / hacked the service, only PBF are available. CSV files are curently unavailable. Please send a mail to davidmasclet@gisgraphy.com if you really need it urgently.